# D3 + VueJs + Typescript | How to import D3.js Library?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, d3.js, webpack, vuejs2

I have to create a Dashboard for my customer using VueJS + Typescript and D3.js.

They are using dotnet vue template: 'dotnet new –install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*' 'dotnet new vue'

Everything is setup on installation: Webpack, Typescript and VueJS

This Webpack setup does not accept `<script lang="ts"></script>` and most of the tutorials uses it to import D3.js library.

Is there any way to reconfigure webpack in this template to accept `<script lang="ts"></script>`?

[Error after I install d3 and d3 typings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvJBU.jpg)

Best

Comment: Is there a reason you can't download D3 (for example, via `npm install d3`) and `import` it inside your Typescript code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know why would you like to use `<script>` instead of the typical `npm` based approach. There are many examples/tutorial in the Internet on that topic. Normally, what you do is a few steps:

1. Install d3 as npm dependency: `npm install --save d3`
2. Since you're writing code in TypeScript, it's helpful to get some type support: `npm install --save-dev @types/d3`
3. In your typescript file import the types by adding the next line at the very top of it: `import * as d3 from "d3";`
4. Use it. `d3.select(...)`

Comment: I think the you mean `npm install --save d3` instead of `npm install --save-dev d3`?

Comment: And probably the types are --save-dev :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have installed d3.js and d3.js typings for typescript. However, when I type in d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg"); everything being underlined in red and compiler gives a lot of errors. I have added image to my original post.

Comment: @Ksistof you can't write it directly in your class. if you wrap it with a function the errors will disappear